# How can i Display mysql database as an array?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm new on wordpress and php.
I have a MySQL database full of user information, like their first names, email,numbers etc..

I want to display an array on an admin page on wordpress but for some reason it is not working here is my code

```php
<?php
require('_connexion.php');
?>
        <?php

// La requete (exemple) : tous les "objet", classés par "id".
$query = "SELECT * FROM form_tab ";
try {
    $pdo_select = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $pdo_select->execute();
    $NbreData = $pdo_select->rowCount();
    $rowAll   = $pdo_select->fetchAll();

}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Erreur SQL : ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br/>';
    die();
}

if ($NbreData != 0) {
?>
       <table id="customers">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Prenom</th>
                <th>Nom</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Tel</th>
                <th>ID</th>          
              <th>Adresse</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
    // pour chaque ligne (chaque enregistrement)
    foreach ($rowAll as $row) {
        // DONNEES A AFFICHER dans chaque cellule de la ligne
?>
           <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['prenom']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['nom']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['tel']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Adresse']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
    } // fin foreach
?>
       </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php
} else {
?>
        pas de données à afficher
        <?php
}
?>
       <?php
echo "<h3>ce tableau contient $NbreData membres</h3>";
?>
```

only the search input is showing

wordpress page : Le site rencontre des difficultés techniques. Veuillez relever la boîte de messagerie du compte administrateur du site pour obtenir des instructions.

Comment: I don't see a search input string anywhere. Are you sure this code is the code for the page you're looking at?

Comment: not sure about the issue with your query, but just FYI, your last 2 columns are out of order

Answer (score 3):

Remove all the spaces while calling a method:
`$e-        >getMessage()`

Also are you sure it's not easier to use something like phpMyAdmin? You may end up with a massive list on your WP dashboard screen otherwise.

Comment: What file exactly do you use to output your results?